# can't connect to mysql remote

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a client on linux and the mysql server on windows

I wanted to connect to mysql remotely 2 computers can ping each other without any problem in mysql server I set the permission correctly so the specified client is allowed to connect

```
WIN IP:  192.168.1.2
Linux IP:192.168.1.3
```

in windows system:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'parsa'@'192.168.1.3' IDENTIFIED BY 'parsa';
flush all privileges;
```

in my linux,in my.cnf I wrote this line in `mysqld` section

```
bind-address=192.168.1.2
```

`skip-networking` was commented and I didn't change it
I restarted the mysql

when I use

```
telnet 192.168.1.2 3306 

telnet:connect to address 192.168.1.2:Connection timed out
```

and using this command:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.2 -u parsa -p parsa
Error 2003:can't connect to mysql server on 192.168.1.2
```

The `firewalls` in both sides are disabled what should I do?

command:`net stats srv`

Statistics since 2/29/2012 4:52:22 PM

```
Sessions accepted                  1
Sessions timed-out                 0
Sessions errored-out               0

Kilobytes sent                     0
Kilobytes received                 0

Mean response time (msec)          0

System errors                      0
Permission violations              0
Password violations                0

Files accessed                     0
Communication devices accessed     0
Print jobs spooled                 0

Times buffers exhausted

  Big buffers                      0
  Request buffers                  0

The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: try `'parsa'@'*'` to see it if it a host issue or connection (ip tables, router, etc)

Comment: Do you have `skip-networking` in your my.cnf? It will override bind-address.

Comment: skip-networking is there but commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Connection timed out` can mean two things:

1. Your server is too busy to respond
2. There is a firewall between your client computer and the server which blocks the connection.

To see how busy the server is, use `uptime`. Load average > 10 means "busy". Load average < 1 means "idle".

If the server is idle, check for the firewall settings on the server, then check the client.

Comment: strange seems you're absolutely right,about fire wall I have this sentence :Incomming connections block all except allowed programs but when the firewall is off! does it affect:-? and about uptime how can I write it in win7?

Comment: I saw uptime 0:01:41:37,I didn't get your mean

Comment: For details how to configure a firewall on Windows, post a question on http://superuser.com/

Comment: you're a great man I appreciate your knowledge so much This was a firewall from Eset Node which was enable and cause a problem Thank you so so so so much! you are really brilliant:)